# Replace all instances of a string on multiple lines

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a file which looks like this

`1234567:abcdefg:X
1234567:abcdefg:X
1234567:abcdefg:X
1234567:abcdefg:X`

I need to replace the end character on each line (the X), to 0. This seems simple but every time I use regex It is either null or `regex.replace` is not a function.
Currently I have `/.*:.*:(.*)/g` for the regex

Comment: `str.replace(/.$/gm, '0')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match the format with the colons except for the last character using a negated character class and a capturing group.

```
^([^:]+:[^:]+:)\S$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `[^:]+:[^:]+:` Match 2 times  not `:`, then match : using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)
- `)` Close group
- `\S` Match a non whitespace char
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nPwVTb/1)

In the replacement, use capturing group 1 followed by a 0

If the last character can not be a colon, use `[^\s:]` instead of `\S`

```js
const regex = /^([^:]+:[^:]+:)\S$/gm;
const str = `1234567:abcdefg:X
1234567:abcdefg:X
1234567:abcdefg:X
1234567:abcdefg:X`;
const subst = `$10`;
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

As **adiga** already answered. I've added two examples (based on **adigas** excellent answer/comment).

```js
const subject = `1234567:abcdefg:X
1234567:abcdefg:X
1234567:abcdefg:X
1234567:abcdefg:X`;

// Regular expression literal
const resultWithLiteral = subject.replace(/.$/gm, '0');

// Regular expression constructor
const expression = new RegExp(/.$/gm);
const resultWithConstructor = subject.replace(expression, '0');

function renderResults() {
  const outputElements = document.querySelectorAll('pre');
  outputElements[0].innerText = resultWithLiteral;
  outputElements[1].innerText = resultWithConstructor;
};
```

```html
<section>
<h1>Result with literal</h1>
<pre>
1234567:abcdefg:X
1234567:abcdefg:X
1234567:abcdefg:X
1234567:abcdefg:X
</pre>
</section>
<section>
<h1>Result with literal</h1>
<pre>
1234567:abcdefg:X
1234567:abcdefg:X
1234567:abcdefg:X
1234567:abcdefg:X
</pre>
</section>
<button onclick="renderResults();">Click to replace</button>
```